# Javascript regex on array

Tags: javascript

I currently have this example array:

```
array = [1.2%, 16%, 9.0%, 8%]
```

I want to get the highest number so I did this:

```
Math.max.apply(null, array);
```

But it shows an error maybe because of the '%'

How can I filter the array using regex? It's my first time using regex on the array. I already spent more than 2 hours I still don't get it.

Here are my works that did not work:

```
array = [1.2%, 16%, 9.0%, 8%].match(/[0-9]*\.?[0-9]/);
array = [1.2%, 16%, 9.0%, 8%].replace(/[0-9]*\.?[0-9]/);
array = [1.2%, 16%, 9.0%, 8%].match(/[\d]+/);
```

Sorry I am new to javascript. Thanks.

Comment: um, that is a syntax error. Do you actually have strings? Arrays do not have match and replace methods. Should be `['1.2%', '16%', '9.0%', '8%']`

Comment: I thunk you should use string values: ['1.2%', '16%', '9.0%', '8%']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the strings to `parseFloat`, then the "%" will be ignored:

```js
let array = ["1.2%", "16%", "9.0%", "8%"];

let result = Math.max(...array.map(parseFloat));

console.log(result);
```

NB: I used the spread syntax here instead of `apply`, just because that is the more modern way to write it (since EcmaScript 2015).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the % symbol isn't valid on a number, so you probably want to strip that first (your array elements will be strings, actually):

```
const array = ['1.2%', '16%', '9.0%', '8%'];
const floats = array.map(e => parseFloat(e.replace('%', ''));
```

Now you have an array of floating numbers, so you can now find out the biggest number:

```
const biggest = Math.max(...floats);
console.log(biggest);
```

Answer (score -1):

You won't need regular expressions at all:

```js
Math.max(...['1.2%', '16%', '9.0%', '8%'].map(e => parseFloat(e)).sort());
// or maybe add the '%' if that's what you're after
Math.max(...['1.2%', '16%', '9.0%', '8%'].map(e => parseFloat(e)).sort()) + '%';
```